# How do I set initial vuex state in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

I have the data I am looking for in a controller and need to set some state in vuex. Do I need to make a second database request, or is there some way for me to pass the value from my controller to vuex?

I am trying to pass the value down as props and change a null state, but when I change the state, the value is still being passed down.

Is there a way to pass the value from the controller to vuex, or do I have to double my requests and make 2 calls just to load the same data?

Answer (score 3):

You can do a second query to fetch the initial state OR get these values through window.App (or whatever).

```
window.App = {
 initialState: {{ !empty($myInitialState) ? json_encode($myInitialState) : '' }}
};
```

In Vue.js, update the initial vuex state using `window.App.initialState`;

```
created () {
  this.$store && this.$store.dispatch('SET_INITIAL_STATE', window.App.initialState || {})
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to get the values without doing a second request?